# Hovered state is not triggered from PointerEnter event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently designing a custom inventory in Unity. Although `OnClick` method works properly for each slot, the `OnHovered` one does not go the same way. The latter was added through an EventTrigger component.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAZGe.png

`OnHovered` can be found in InventorySlot script linked to the button, it only contains a one-line print, but, which prints nothing actually. Besides, I specify that there's an EventSystem in the scene which includes the Standalone Input Module.

```cs
public void OnHovered()
{
    Debug.Log("HOVERED");
}
```

I know this is some very basic stuff but I'm unable to figure out what's the problem about, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid simply adding the event trigger component isn't enough.
You have two options:
1. Have your inventory slot script derive from EventTrigger and implement the desired method.
2. Add the IPointerEnter interface implentation to your script and use the OnPointerEnter method.

Hope I was clear
Good luck

Comment: Thank you very much, the second option worked in my case!